# ImageButton Based On If Condition

Tags: android

I have implemented an `ImageButton` which changes images based on 3 conditions, one of the condition is set as follows:

```
if (Local().equals(Remote)) {
    ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.sync_green);
} else {
    ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.sync_red);
}
```

This works but after a few seconds the app crashes with the following log:

```
06-20 11:58:27.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2278): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-160
06-20 11:58:27.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2278): Process: com.twostarii.asyncdownload, PID: 2278
06-20 11:58:27.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2278): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
06-20 11:58:27.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2278):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6247)
06-20 11:58:27.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2278):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:902)
06-20 11:58:27.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2278):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4637)
06-20 11:58:27.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2278):     at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:11690)
06-20 11:58:27.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2278):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11654)
06-20 11:58:27.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2278):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11638)
06-20 11:58:27.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2278):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:402)
06-20 11:58:27.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2278):     at com.twostarii.asyncdownload.AndroidDownloadFileByProgressBarActivity$1.run(AndroidDownloadFileByProgressBarActivity.java:172)
```

Comment: Post your complete code here

Comment: You can't change the drawable because your not on the main UI thread as the logcat is stating here - the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the drawable because your not on the main UI thread.

try doing something like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // code here to run on UI Thread
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you Mark - It worked perfectly, I will read up more on that

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is you are trying to modify some of your UI elements from a new thread that you created. You can't do that. Only the main thread can modify the UI elements.

Here are two things you can do to solve your problem:

1.) Use the runOnUiThread method

2.) Use the AsyncTask API

Personally, I'd recommend using AsyncTask. You can check on Google about how to use it